# Cross-platform subscriptions in Android app

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I'm setting up an Android video viewing service that will also have a web counterpart. Firstly is there a way using Google Plays billing services to manage subscriptions to a cross-platform account? It seems like the subscription would be tied to the google play account. If not am I able to use a service like Stripe for payments, and still get this app allowed on the play store?

I've been able to setup subscriptions through google play billing, but need to be able to use generic emails not just google accounts. As I need to facilitate cross-platform usage.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a documentation regarding Google Play Service Policy in [Monetization and Ads](https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/),

> Developers offering products within another category of app downloaded
> on Google Play must use [Google Play In-app Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview) as the method of
> payment, except for the following cases:
>
> - Payment is solely for physical products
> - Payment is for digital content that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g. songs that can be played on other music players).

Subscription services, such as streaming music, video, book, or other media services; digital publications, including when bundled with a physical edition; and social networking services are supported by Google Play In-app Billing.

Kindly read the full documentation for more details.

Comment: Yes, but the issue is adapting this to cross-platform usage. A user logs into the website to view paid content associated with their email address. The user then logs into the app where he can view his paid content, and purchases another subscription. But now the subscription is tied to his google play account, whereas I need a way to tie it to a generic account.

Comment: This means that the subscription must be tied to Google Play Account in order to use the billing in GPS.

Comment: So there is no solution in regards to cross-platform purchases using Google Play Billing, and I am forced to use Google Play Billing if I want my application to be available in the Google Play Store?

Comment: Yes. You will need to use Google Play Billing for GPS.